# how to direct login activity to different user profile

Tags: java, android, authentication

I'm doing an android application and after login in i have two different types of users profiles in my case a simple client and and a pharmacist with advanced configurations ,I have been looking in the internet about how to direct my login activity according to the user account registered in my database but it didn't help, i'm using android studio. this is my loginactivity.java

```
package com.example.yh.log;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private EditText TextUserName;
    private EditText TextPassword;
    public static final String USER_NAME = "USERNAME";
    String username;
    String password;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



}
public void onLoginClick(View view){
TextUserName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editusername);
TextPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editpassword);

username=TextUserName.getText().toString();
password=TextPassword.getText().toString();
if(username.isEmpty())
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Entrez votre username",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
else if(password.isEmpty())
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Entrez votre mot de passe",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
else {
    String urlString = "http://192.168.173.1/Search/login.php";
    LoginTask loginTask = new LoginTask();
    loginTask.execute(urlString);
}
}
private class LoginTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>
{
    private Dialog loadingDialog;
  @Override
  protected void onPreExecute() {
  super.onPreExecute();
 loadingDialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "Please wait", "Loading...");
}
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        HttpURLConnection c=null;
        try {
            String urlString=params[0];
            URL url=new URL(urlString);
            c=(HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            c.setRequestMethod("POST");
            c.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
            c.setDoInput(true);
            c.setDoOutput(true);
            c.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            String s = "username="+username+"&password=" + password;
        c.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(s.getBytes().length);
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(c.getOutputStream());
        out.print(s);
        out.close();

        c.connect();
        int mStatusCode = c.getResponseCode();
        String result="";
        switch (mStatusCode) {
            case 200:
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(c.getInputStream()));
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line;
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line).append("\n");
                }
                br.close();
                result =  sb.toString();

        }
        return result;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        return "Error connecting to server";
    } finally {
        if (c != null) {
            try {
                c.disconnect();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
               Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        }
    }
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        //super.onPostExecute(s);
        String ss = s;
        loadingDialog.dismiss();
        if(ss.equals("successclient\n")) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, UserProfile.class);
        }else {
            if (ss.equals("successpharmacien\n")) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, PharmacienProfile.class);

            intent.putExtra(USER_NAME, username);
            finish();
            startActivity(intent);
        }else{
               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ss, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }}
}
}
```

this is the php code

```
<?php


 try
{
    // connecting to MySQL
    $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=application;charset=utf8', 'root', '');

}
catch(Exception $e)
{

// In case of an error, we display a message and stop everything
    die('Erreur : '.$e->getMessage());

}
    //Getting values 
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];



//contact surgat
// display every input one after another

$listephar = $bdd->query("SELECT * FROM phamacien  WHERE emailpharmacien='$username' AND motpasspharmacien='$password'");

$listeclient = $bdd->query("SELECT * FROM client  WHERE emailclient='$username' AND motpass='$password'");

while ($pharmacien = $listephar->fetch())
{

    //if we got some result 
    if(isset($pharmacien)){
        //displaying success 
        echo "successpharmacien";
        }else{
        //displaying failure


while ($client = $listeclient->fetch())
{
    if (isset($client)){
            echo "successclient";
        }else{
        //displaying failure
        echo "failure";


}
}}}
$listephar->closeCursor();      
$listeclient->closeCursor(); 
?>
```

Comment: comments should be in English, not in French

Answer (score 2):

After successful login return the user type from the server. Now as you have the user type in your hand you can simply do

```
if(ss=="success") {


    if(usertype=="guest")
    {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,UserProfile.class);         
    }else{
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AdminProfile.class);
    }
    intent.putExtra(USER_NAME, username);
    startActivity(intent);
}
else{
       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "invalide username or password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}}
```

Comment: but i'm doing the test in the php code and i'm geting the error in " fetch() " i'll edit the code